# For a small dataset, should I apply an adjustment to the 3-sigma rule when using it for outlier detection?

Tags: outliers

Standard deviations for small datasets (for example, less than 20 data points) are more volatile/higher variance than those for large datasets. If we want to use the 3-sigma rule for outlier detection, should we apply any adjustment for small sample size?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Could you expand a little bit what you hope to achieve with the procedure? Why do you want to exclude outliers and why do you intend to use the 3-sigma rule?

Comment: I need to do outlier detection for my work. 3 sigma rule is a simple way for doing so. It works well for large datasets, but it doesn't work well for small datasets. Also look for any good alternatives for this purpose.

Comment: @konomonte do you mean you do not have a choice and must exclude outliers if they exist? What are you going to do after excluding outliers? It's difficult to answer questions with such limited information.

Comment: I want to flag potential outliers and inform users. Not necessary to remove them. For example, a univariate dataset: [1,2,2,1,3,2,4,1,1,3,2,2,80,300]. Predominately most values are between 1 and 3 , so obviously 300 and 80 are outliers. 300 can be identified by 3-sigma rule, but 80 can't. So I am looking for a reliable method to determine if 80 is an outlier. I understand 3-simga rule is sensitive to large outliers.

Comment: The easiest place to start is the interquartile range and Tukey's 1.5 * IQR below the 1st quartile and above the 3rd quartile. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966331/why-john-tukey-set-1-5-iqr-to-detect-outliers-instead-of-1-or-2